# PHP Str_replace doesn't work on JSON_DECODE

Tags: php

I want to delete the html tags from the database, but it does not change in any way. where is the mistake?

Nothing changes when I print the data in the database. But when I manually type in `$text` it succeeds ... error I can't understand.
My writing as the 3rd way is successful

1.

```
$seo = json_decode($service_['page_seo'], true);
$text = $seo['description'] ? $seo['description'] : $service_['page_content'];

$replace = array('<p>','</p>','<li>','</li>','<ul>','</ul>','&nbsp;');
echo str_replace($replace,'',$text);

output
<p>Al Sindy Company is a logistics, transfer and storage company founded in 2004 by Khalil İbrahim Yasin in Duhok, Iraq. Al Sindy Company; Aiming to excellence in logistics, transfer and storage services it provides, it aims to grow by using the qualified human resources in the most effective way. Open Branch in 2018 was in Turkey. Al Sindy Company provides services to its customers with its worldwide partners who have been carefully selected for the changing logistics needs of the changing world, with its over 40 staff, warehouses and transfer areas in Mersin, Cizre, Iraq Zaho, Iraq Bedrike, Iraq Baghdad. Al Sindy Company blends its dignified and deep-rooted past with the changes and developments in the world; they are constantly working with the mission of producing newer, better and higher quality products and services.</p>
```

2. 

```
var_dump($text);
string(851) "<p>Al Sindy Company is a logistics, transfer and storage company founded in 2004 by Khalil İbrahim Yasin in Duhok, Iraq. Al Sindy Company; Aiming to excellence in logistics, transfer and storage services it provides, it aims to grow by using the qualified human resources in the most effective way. Open Branch in 2018 was in Turkey. Al Sindy Company provides services to its customers with its worldwide partners who have been carefully selected for the changing logistics needs of the changing world, with its over 40 staff, warehouses and transfer areas in Mersin, Cizre, Iraq Zaho, Iraq Bedrike, Iraq Baghdad. Al Sindy Company blends its dignified and deep-rooted past with the changes and developments in the world; they are constantly working with the mission of producing newer, better and higher quality products and services.</p>"
```

3. 

String

```
$text =" <p>Al Sindy Company is a logistics, transfer and storage company founded in 2004 by Khalil İbrahim Yasin in Duhok, Iraq. Al Sindy Company; Aiming to excellence in logistics, transfer and storage services it provides, it aims to grow by using the qualified human resources in the most effective way. Open Branch in 2018 was in Turkey. Al Sindy Company provides services to its customers with its worldwide partners who have been carefully selected for the changing logistics needs of the changing world, with its over 40 staff, warehouses and transfer areas in Mersin, Cizre, Iraq Zaho, Iraq Bedrike, Iraq Baghdad. Al Sindy Company blends its dignified and deep-rooted past with the changes and developments in the world; they are constantly working with the mission of producing newer, better and higher quality products and services.</p>";

$replace = array('<p>','</p>','<li>','</li>','<ul>','</ul>','&nbsp;');
echo str_replace($replace,'',$text);

output:

Al Sindy Company is a logistics, transfer and storage company founded in 2004 by Khalil İbrahim Yasin in Duhok, Iraq. Al Sindy Company; Aiming to excellence in logistics, transfer and storage services it provides, it aims to grow by using the qualified human resources in the most effective way. Open Branch in 2018 was in Turkey. Al Sindy Company provides services to its customers with its worldwide partners who have been carefully selected for the changing logistics needs of the changing world, with its over 40 staff, warehouses and transfer areas in Mersin, Cizre, Iraq Zaho, Iraq Bedrike, Iraq Baghdad. Al Sindy Company blends its dignified and deep-rooted past with the changes and developments in the world; they are constantly working with the mission of producing newer, better and higher quality products and services.
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with the sample text you've provided in the question. Can you include a `var_dump` of the the text variable that fails?

Comment: I wrote the var_dump result to the thread

Comment: That doesn't produce the failure. What you had in the previous version would explain why it doesn't replace, as there was a whole ton of inline styling inside the elements.

Comment: The first step of debugging is always to break the problem down: you know what the result of `json_decode` is, so you don't need the actual JSON, you can just hard-code that value. You can go further, and hard-code `$text` - it looks like you already tried, but then overwrite it two lines down. Keep narrowing the problem down to a [mcve].

Comment: You are assigning a value to `$text` in two places. The second will override the first. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @kmoser yes I just want to print a "description"  ```$text```answer to the question

Comment: Then why does your `var_dump()` example show the first value of `$text` but below that you are assigning another value: `$text = $seo['description'] ? $seo['description'] : $service_['page_content'];`?

Comment: I edited the question, when I pull the data from the database, the replacement cannot be processed.
But I could not understand that the manual modification is being processed

Comment: The string you posted in the second example contains only 839 characters while `var_dump()` reports 929.

Comment: deleted editor tags are available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `strip_tags()`;

`strip_tags()` tries to return the string after removing all null bytes, all `PHP` and `HTML` tags from the code.

so you can do : `echo strip_tags($text);`

See https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I already used this but the ineffective element, my aim is to remove the html tags and "div, li, ul, style ..."

Comment: What is the PHP version that you're using please ?

Comment: the version i use is php 7.4

Comment: Okay. Try to see if your problem is not already with the treatments you do before doing str_replace ($ replace, '', $ text)

Comment: how do i achieve this?